# sbt sbtversion throwing error

Tags: debian, sbt

When i type sbt sbtversion in the debian shell, i am getting the following error

```
$ sbt sbtversion
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
   at java.io.File.performCreate(libgcj.so.15)
   at java.io.File.createNewFile(libgcj.so.15)
   at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:34)
   at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
   at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.$init$(Proxy.scala:32)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$ScalaProvider.<init>(Launch.scala:110)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$1.apply(Launch.scala:84)
   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.namespace.NamespaceRule.newEntry(Cache.scala:17)
   at org.apache.ivy.plugins.namespace.NamespaceRule.apply(Cache.scala:12)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:86)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:49)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:43)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:68)
   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:25)
   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
   at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like you lack privileges to create a file, though the trace fails to show where exactly. Maybe use `strace` to fund out.

Comment: Thanks triplee. You are right. May be the exception is too misleading.